# Replacing specific lines in multiple files using bash

Tags: bash, loops, replace, sed

I'm relatively new to bash scripting, having started out of the need to manage my simulations on supercomputers. I'm currently stuck on writing a script to change specific lines in my pbs files.

There's 2 stages to my problem. First, I need to replace a number of lines in a text file (another script), and overwrite that file for my later use. The rough idea is:

> Replace lines 27, 28 and 29 of `'filename005'` with `'text1=000'`, `'text2=005'` and `'text3=010'`

Next, I'd like to do that recursively for a set of text files with numbered suffixes, and the numbering influences the replaced text.

My code so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i = 1; i < 10; i++))
    do
    let NUM=i*5
    let OLD=NUM-5
    let NOW=NUM
    let NEW=NUM+5

    let FILE=$(printf "filename%03g" $NUM)
    sed "27 c\text1=$OLD" $FILE
    sed "28 c\text2=$NOW" $FILE
    sed "29 c\text3=$NEW" $FILE
done
```

I know there are some errors in the last 4 lines of my code, and I'm still studying up on the proper way to implement `sed`. Appreciate any tips!

Thanks!
CS

Comment: A more sustainable approach might be to have your scripts read their parameters from a configuration file or a set of environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the first line of your specification:

```
Replace lines 27:29 of filename005, with text1=000; text2=005; text3=010
```

That becomes:

```
sed -e '27,29c\
text1=000\
text2=005\
text3=010' filename005
```

Rinse and repeat.  The backslashes indicate to `sed` that the change continues.  It's easier on yourself if your actual data lines do not need to end with backslashes.

You can play with:

```
seq 1 35 |
sed -e '27,29c\
text1=000\
text2=005\
text3=010'
```

to see what happens without risking damage to precious files.  Given the specification lines, you could write a `sed` script to generate `sed` scripts from the specification (though I'd be tempted to use Perl or `awk` instead; indeed, I'd probably do the whole job in Perl).

Comment: Hi @Johnathan Leffler, thanks for that, I'll check and up-vote when I'm back at my office on Monday.

Comment: What do you mean by 'replace the text'?  The answer's probably 'Yes', but until I know what you want to do, I can't tell you how to do it.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguous question, I asked before thinking. I'll try your earlier suggestion first before refining my question.

Comment: Hi @Johnathan, I tried your first suggested code on a simple case: replacing lines 27,28 and 29 in filename005 with the text, but there are no changes to those lines when I reopened the file. Having said that, when I executed my script, the contents of my file with the replaced lines are displayed on my terminal. Do I have to specify the original filename to overwrite it?

Comment: The code I showed displays the edited output on standard output.  If you want to write update the file, you have to organize that. If you're using GNU `sed` and your files are neither symlinks nor multiply linked, then you can safely use the `-i` option to overwrite. If you're dealing with symlinks or multiply link files, then you should write to a temporary file and then _copy_ the temporary file over the original — GNU `sed -i` does not handle this. If you don't have GNU `sed` but you have simple files, you can write to temporary and _move_ the temporary to the original (quicker than copy).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to get my code to work after finding out that for in-line replacement, I need to write it to a temporary file. So, with the recursive loop and multi-line replacement (and other small tweaks):

```
for ((i = 1; i < 10; i++ ))
    do
    let NUM=i*5
    let OLD=NUM-5
    let NOW=NUM
    let NEW=NUM+5

    FILE=`printf "filename%03g" $NUM`

    sed -e "27,29 c\
    OLD=$OLD\n\
    NOW=$NOW\n\
    NEW=$NEW" $FILE >temp.tmp && mv temp.tmp $FILE
done
```

Do let me know if there is a more elegant way to use `sed` in this context. Thanks again @Johnathan!